# Spring autowiring order

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I am curretly doing a spring task that recuries me to create bean methods for Video and Channel objects. Each created video must have a localdate with value of one day after the previous one. Everything is ok but there is one problem. I have these variables in my test class

```
    @Autowired
    Channel channel;

    @Autowired
    Video video;

    @Autowired
    Video otherVideo;

    @Autowired
    Video anotherOtherVideo;
```

these are created after the channel object so when new Video object is created with the bean it is 3 days of.
This is the configuration file

```
@Configuration
public class ChannelWithInjectedPrototypeVideoConfig {
    private LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.of(2023, 10, 1, 10, 0);

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public Video video() {
        date = date.plusDays(1);
        return new Video("Cat Failure Compilation", date);
    }

    @Bean
    public Channel channel() {
        Channel channel = new EphemeralChannel();
        for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
            channel.addVideo(video());
        }
        return channel;
    }
}
```

How can I make it so these three are created before the Channel object (without changing the test class of course)? I tried @DependsOn and @Order but they didn't work. If there are other possible solutions please share them too.

Comment: You  increment the date manually with each call. What exactly do you mean by "*[the video] is 3 days off*"?

Comment: When the channel object is autowired 14 videos with sequential dates are created, then 3 videos are autowired increasing the date class variable by 3 days. So when a new video is added to the channel its date is off by 3 days

Answer (score 0):

You could move the date variable into the channel block:

```
@Configuration
public class ChannelWithInjectedPrototypeVideoConfig {

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public Video video(LocalDateTime date) {
        return new Video("Cat Failure Compilation", date);
    }

    @Bean
    public Channel channel() {
        LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.of(2023, 10, 1, 10, 0);
        Channel channel = new EphemeralChannel();
        for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
            date = date.plusDays(1);
            channel.addVideo(video(date));
        }
        return channel;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).